# Check weather my mail id is entered correct

Tags: regex, validation, email

How do i check whether my email address contains the business id that is required using regular expressions? 
Ex: i need to check that the email address "myemail@businessid.com" contains "businessid" on it or any other email ids like gmail,yahoo etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need RegExp for that you can simply use `includes`

```js
'myemail@businessid.com'.includes('businessid', 'gmail', 'yahoo') // true
```

---

Using RegExp:

```js
/businessid|gmail|yahoo/.test('myemail@businessid.com') // true
```

or

```js
new RegExp('businessid|gmail|yahoo').test('myemail@businessid.com') // true
```

---

**Note**: you might want to check that there is an extension after your domain (`.com`, `.net`) and that the domain is in the part after the `@` sign.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to match `businessid.org`, `businessid2.com` etc.

Simply ensuring that the string ends in `businessid.com` could be sufficient:

```
businessid\.com$
```

The following regex adds some additional validation, making sure that the string contains an `@` with at least one character in front of it:

```
^[^@]+@(?:[^.]*\.)?businessid\.com$
```

Matches:

```
myemail@businessid.com
youremail@businessid.com
myemail@subdomain.businessid.com
```

Does not match:

```
myemail@businessid2.com
myemail@businessid.org
```